# getting error : Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused) in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have uploaded my site to `aws`, created mysql database, i checked the connection which is working, put the same connection under settings.py, but i am still getting error `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)`, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'HOST': '*****.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': '*****'
    }
}
```

error :

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://ec2-54-157-178-122.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
Django Version:     3.0.6
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Exception Location:     /home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect, line 630
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/env/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.9
Python Path:    

['/home/ubuntu/django-bhuriyo',
 '/home/ubuntu/env/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 24 May 2020 13:30:46 +0000
```